# aspectjWeaver with fat jar

Tags: sbt, aspectj, sbt-assembly

Please can you let me know how I can refer aspectjweaver once it is inside fat jar, because I have to refer same during run time as :

java -javaagent:aspectj-weaver.jar my-app.jar

I am using sbt assembly.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The question is unclear. Do you want to refer to _aspectjweaver.jar_ from the command line as shown in your question or do you want to use it programmatically during runtime? These two options are completely different.

Comment: Oh, and BTW: If you have control over your fat JAR - you seem to because you managed to package _aspectjweaver.jar_ inside it - why don't you not simply use AspectJ compile-time weaving and just put _aspectjrt.jar_ inside your fat JAR? This is much easier.

Comment: I am using http://kamon.io/introduction/get-started/ , as per manual process I can use aspectj-weaver.jar, but as you suggested I would love to use aspectjrt.jar  to have compile time weaving. We are using sbt based build process, so we can bundle aspectjrt.jar , but not sure Kamon.io will able to support same or not.

Answer (score 2):

I just build a simple [example](https://github.com/kamon-io/Kamon/tree/master/kamon-examples/kamon-autoweave-example) using `kamon-autoweave` and `sbt-assemby` in order to make a fat jar. When  we do this, we need pay attention to the [merge strategy](https://github.com/kamon-io/Kamon/blob/master/kamon-examples/kamon-autoweave-example/build.sbt#L28-L62) for the `aop.xml` files. (this also apply when passing the `AspectjWeaver` as `javaagent`)

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead with kamon-autoweave (https://github.com/kamon-io/Kamon/tree/master/kamon-autoweave) to avoid javaagent and jar file in the path.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you've done that?

Comment: I have included KamonAutoWeave , for example in sbt based project add following as dependency:   "io.kamon" % "kamon-autoweave_2.11" % "0.6.1" <br>  so during assembly process this jar will be bundled with fat jar.  When you start your app with java or java2 , it will try to find kamon.autoweave.Autoweave , which is part of  kamon-autoweave, and will start the javaaganet. More info refer this code: https://github.com/kamon-io/Kamon/blob/master/kamon-autoweave/src/main/scala/kamon/autoweave/Autoweave.scala

Comment: so you say it's just enough to add the autoweave dependency, and run the jar normally? Or you also need to do something from your app code, like create that class and call `attach` method somewhere early in the run time?

Comment: from agent and weaving perspective this is good enough. Yes you have to start Kamon.start() to make use of Kamon, let me know if you find any issue, I can help here.